Identify this movie about ghouls in a desert and a car stonehenge
I watched this movie around 2006, on Foxtel(movie channel) in Australia.
It was set in a desert town where something scary was going on.
I remember one or two characters descending into a manhole or tunnel in the streets of the town. After a while they run into some sort of ghouls or vampire like creatures and they promptly run away. 
They escape by climbing up the ladder out of the manhole/tunnel and the creatures do not follow them for some reason. I am unsure if it was because of light sensitivity or an action the characters took.
The only other scene I can remember is them reaching a sort of car stonehenge in the desert and I believe the movie ended shortly after this event.
The movie was in colour and I believe it was a recent release at the time.

Sounds like they ended up in car henge.

this reminds me about one of the scene in maze runner scorch trial.
